# run time 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of about 3000, i am using the below word find to pick out the term "Incoterm   tariff C" and delete a big section of blank data. (via column A)

When running the below it will stop at about line 350, and spit  out an error message "Run Time 13, Type mismatch". It stops on the highlighted line below.  Why?

```
Sub wordfind()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = LastRow To 1 Step -1
   If Range("A" & I).Value = "Incoterm   Tariff C" Then ' error occurs here
      Range("A" & I).Select
      Selection.EntireRow.delete
      ActiveCell.Offset(-13).Select
     ActiveCell.Resize(12).Select
      Selection.EntireRow.delete
   End If
 Next I

End Sub
```

- it did a little more this time. fot stuck on A296, contains the phrase "Hawb       Org Dst"
  dont know why, it should skip over this line seeking the next "Incoterm    tariff C" line
  checked the incoterm line before it, and after, which is fine.

Comment: Ok, I have a question for you. It's really completely out of left field and thinking outside the box, but here it goes: *Have you looked to see what's in that cell?*

Comment: Also a much better way to achieve what you want is using [AUTOFILTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Comment: BTW you may be getting that error because your cell probably has a #Formula Error like #NA or #Value or #Div etc... ;)

Comment: Yep, looked in the cell, cant see anything wrong. The data in the cells is converted from a .txt file. no formulas or anything.

Comment: What exact text is in the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
If Range("A" & I).Value = "Incoterm   Tariff C" Then
```

with:

```
If Range("A" & I).Text = "Incoterm   Tariff C" Then
```